# Error while running linux command through Runtime.getRuntime().exec

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I am trying to run following command in my Java program

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls -lrt service/logs/post/level2.log | awk '{print $9}'");
or
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls -lrt service/logs/post/level2* | awk '{print $9}'");
```

it gives me following error

```
ls: 0653-341 The file | does not exist.
ls: 0653-341 The file awk does not exist.
ls: 0653-341 The file '{print does not exist.
ls: 0653-341 The file $9}' does not exist.
```

Kindly help me

Answer (score 9):

Pipes are a shell-based construct, not actual runnable commands.  There are two options to do this as I see it:

1. Do the piping yourself within Java.  Invoke the `ls` command first, get a handle to its `OutputStream` and then invoke `awk` connecting the first `Process`'s output to the second `Process`' input stream.
2. Invoke the bash shell directly from Java, passing in the entire command as an argument to bash's `-c` parameter.  That way all the piping is done *within* the single process.

As for the token-based errors, you should be invoking these commands with an array of strings; each element represents a token of the command line.  So try, for example:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "ls", "-lrt", "service/logs/post/level2.log" });
```

in order to invoke the ls command.  I don't think this is *strictly* necessary in this case, but it will be for the `awk` command, since Java doesn't know anything about shell-specific quoting rules, so by default tokenises a single-string input on the space character.  That's why your awk script was being split in two.

---

*Edit* (in response to comments):  In the first option, I meant simply that you're able to pipe the output between the two processes yourself, in Java.

Imagine if you've created a process as so:

```
Process ls = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls -lrt service/logs/post/level2.log");
```

Now, this process will run and generate some output (which we know is going to be a line describing that file).  We can get the stream for this output like so:

```
InputStream lsOut = ls.getInputStream();
```

Now, we want to run that awk process:

```
Process awk = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "awk", "{print $9}"});
```

The awk process of course will sit there are the moment waiting for input, since it knows it's going to be reading from stdin.  So, we grab the input stream that it's going to be using:

```
OutputStream awkIn = awk.getOutputStream();
```

Now, the piping bit - we read the output of the ls command and pass it into the input for awk:

```
// TODO add buffering, error handling, probably run this in a separate thread
int datum = lsOut.read();
while (datum != -1)
{
    awkIn.write(datum);
    datum = lsOut.read();
}
```

This reads the output of `ls` (byte-by-byte for simplicity, using byte array buffers would be much faster but I'm trying to illustrate the concept simply) and writes it to the input of `awk`.

Then it's just a matter of reading the output from the `awk` process and dealing with it as you see fit.

Comment: Sorry dear i am not able to under stand a little kindly help.

Comment: i need to understand the part first process output to the second process input stream.

Comment: @Andrzej Doyle : Just want to check : Would executing Runtime.getRuntime().exec("file.sh") work or not even this?

Comment: after your comment i tried the following code
Process p = null;
BufferedReader stdInput = null;
BufferedReader stdError = null;
String s = null;            
String[] cmmd=new String[]{"ls -lrt"};            
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls -lrt service/logs/post/level2.log");
stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(p.getOutputStream())), true);
out.print("awk '{print $9}'");
stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));

Comment: @Xorty - it depends on the underlying OS as to how it handles the file.  I suspect it would work on *Nix OSes so long as the file was executable and the shabang was declared properly.  Java is basically just sending a call to the OS - "run this".

Comment: Dear which stream will have the final output tried to use lsOut but no output.

Comment: @abhishekgem84: the final output will be from the `awk` process' output, i.e. `awk.getInputStream()`.  And I'd prefer if you didn't call me "dear".

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle This is a nice response. I am trying to remotely locate a pid to kill a process running on a server but controlled by a user via calls from a browser. Getting the pid has proven to be quite difficult without any handle, but now I think I've got it! Thanks!

Comment: I was also not getting that helpful error output due to the exec() being invoked on the other side of the connection. :(